# Change setTimeout value

Tags: javascript, settimeout

How to change setTimeout value on console?

Comment: open it in source tab, edit , save it, rerun it?

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy the current timeout

```
var timer;
$('#startTimer').click(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        //...
    },5000)
});

$('#endTimer').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        //...
    },0)
});
```

Comment: Can you post your exact requirement and also could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to change the timer from 5s to 0s, so you can destroy the old timer using clearTimeout() and start a new timer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a way to execute the function immediately instead of waiting for the timer to expire.

You can define your timer function outside of the click function, and inject it as an argument. You also need to return the timerId from the click function so you can clear the timer.

Something like this should work:

```
var delayed = function() {
  console.log("It happened late");
};

var click = function(a, b, delayed) {
  if(a !== b) {
    return setTimeout(delayed, 5000);
  }
  // If a and b are equal, we don't do anything
  return null;
};

var timerId = click(1, 2, delayed);
if(timerId) {
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  setTimeout(delayed, 0);
}
```

When you run this in the console, the text "It happened late" is executed immediately, and there is no delayed execution of the delayed function.